# need regex for removing section of file in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to parse a large file that is typically thousands of lines, and remove a certain section from each match. I want to do it using regex in Notepad++, but am unsure on how to do it. For instance, here is a small sample of what I am looking at:

```
access-list inside line 25 extended permit tcp host 10.1.1.1 any
access-list inside line 26 extended permit tcp host 10.2.1.1 any
access-list inside line 27 extended permit tcp host 10.3.1.1 any
access-list inside line 28 extended permit tcp host 10.4.1.1 any
access-list inside line 29 extended permit tcp host 192.168.100.10 any
access-list outside line 1 extended permit tcp host 192.168.101.10 any
access-list outside line 2 extended permit tcp host 192.168.102.10 any
access-list outside line 3 extended permit tcp host 192.168.103.10 any
```

Imagine the above for thousands of lines. I need the script to remove "line xx" (xx being each unique line number) so only a space is left between the previous and latter word:

```
access-list inside extended permit tcp host 10.1.1.1 any
access-list inside extended permit tcp host 10.2.1.1 any
access-list inside extended permit tcp host 10.3.1.1 any
access-list inside extended permit tcp host 10.4.1.1 any
access-list inside extended permit tcp host 10.5.1.1 any
access-list outside extended permit tcp host 192.168.101.10 any
access-list outside extended permit tcp host 192.168.102.10 any
access-list outside extended permit tcp host 192.168.103.10 any
```

Can this easily be done? (I am not familiar with regex.)

Comment: A google for "notepad++ regex tutorial" will give you plenty of relevant information.

Answer (score -1):

Not completely familiar with the Notepad++ find/replace functionality, but the regex you need is  `line \d+`

which is the word "line" delimited by spaces followed by one or more digits. If you replace that with an empty string, it'll just leave the space after the line number.

Comment: that worked. thank you!!!